# Deploying Rails App with Capistrano - "ERROR: Repository not found."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm having trouble using Capistrano to deploy a Rails app to an EC2 instance.  I am developing the new app for my work on my personal laptop.  I have two Github accounts (personal and work).  I tried to add my personal public key but Github refused because my personal Github account was already associated with it.  So, as a result I have two sets of private/public keys on my laptop.

I added my work public key (`~/.ssh/work_rsa.pub`) to my work Github account.  I created a new private repository under a Github Organization (referred to as WorkOrg) that my work Github account owns (I'm an admin user in that org).

Then I had to create an alias so that git would use my work private key when pushing to Github.  Here's how my `~/.ssh/config` looks:

```
# work account
Host github.com-work
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_rsa
```

I then had to change the remote origin url to: `git@github.com-work:WorkOrg/work_reports.git` so that I could run `$ git push` without having to supply my username and password info every time.  So, I can now push/pull just fine in this new repo (`work_reports`) on my laptop.

I also setup an EC2 instance (ubuntu 14.04) and created a user `deploy` that I can SSH into (using the same `~/.ssh/work_rsa` key).  I copied over my `work_rsa` into `/home/deploy/.ssh/work_rsa` so that I could push/pull from that EC2 instance.

I'm now ready to use Capistrano to setup automated deployments to my EC2 instance.  When I run `$ cap production deploy:check --trace` it fails after this:

```
INFO [bb69f764] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/work_reports/git-ssh.sh as deploy@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [bb69f764] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2 /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/work_reports/git-ssh.sh )
INFO [bb69f764] Finished in 0.046 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
DEBUG [943f7c42] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h git@github.com:WorkOrg/work_reports.git as deploy@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
DEBUG [943f7c42] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/work_reports/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h git@github.com:WorkOrg/work_reports.git )
DEBUG [943f7c42] Error: Repository not found.
DEBUG [943f7c42]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [943f7c42]    
DEBUG [943f7c42]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [943f7c42]    and the repository exists.
```

Here's my `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user 
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.2'
```

Here's my `/config/deploy.rb` file:

```
lock '3.2.1'
set :application, 'work_reports'
set :deploy_user, 'deploy'
set :scm, :git
#set :repo_url, 'git@github.com-work:WorkOrg/work_reports.git'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:WorkOrg/work_reports.git'
set :branch, ENV['REVISION'] || ENV['BRANCH'] || "master"
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, paranoid: true, keys: "~/.ssh/work_rsa" }
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/work_reports'
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

And here's my `/config/deploy/production.rb` file:

```
set :stage, :production
server 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

I even tried using the aliased remote origin url (`set :repo_url, 'git@github.com-work:WorkOrg/work_reports.git'`) in the `deploy.rb` file but I got the same error.

**Is there something I'm not configuring properly so that I can deploy my Rails app to EC2 using Capistrano?**

Comment: What happens when you type ssh -T git@github.com from your EC2 instance?

Comment: I get "Permission denied (publickey).".  But if I try to clone the private repository above (`git clone git@github.com-work:WorkOrg/work_reports.git`) then it clones successfully because I've added the same alias to my `~/.ssh/config` file on the EC2 instance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, according to this it looks like you did everything right: http://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: @fatfrog I was digging through Capistrano and it looks like since I'm using multiple private keys I need to set `:ssh_options { forward_agent: false }` in my `/config/deploy.rb` file.  After I changed that I was able to deploy using Capistrano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my `/config/deploy.rb` file in order for Capistrano to actually use the `work_rsa` private key :

```
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: false, paranoid: true, keys: "~/.ssh/work_rsa" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late in the train here.

My problem turned out to be changed repo name. This was fixed when I SSH'd to the server, then changed the repo URI in git config located at `/to/project/repo/config`.

Weird thing that this was only happening in Travis CI build. Also, no problem when I checked with `capistrano-ssh-doctor`.